# Does creatine help in fat loss?

Tags: weight-loss, bodybuilding

Creatine can help in building strength but I am curious if it benefits fatloss as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is very little to no evidence that creatine helps with fat loss. Its main use is to increase power output.

[Examine.com](https://examine.com/supplements/creatine/) has a pretty extensive list of all the stuff creatine does. The one section regarding fat states:

> Creatine reliably increases lean mass (water at first, then muscle with more prolonged supplementation) but does not appear to significantly alter fat mass.

Comment: To add to this: Creatine does increase endurance, in due time more endurance in cardio and weight lifting can help with fat loss but there is no direct evidence

Comment: Yes. Creatine improves performance which improves energy output which aides in fat loss over time (when also in a caloric deficit). I interpreted this question as asking whether creatine by itself acts as a sort of fat burner. It does not.

Comment: Slight misconceptions - Creatine does nothing by itself. It *enables* extra work, by providing phosphates to regenerate ATP from ADP. Technospeak aside, it just means that your muscles can use this for energy where they might otherwise be tapped out. It's like having an extra gallon of gas in a can. That doesn't make your car faster or more efficient, but it does let it work longer. That extra work is what increases endurance or enables extra work in the weight room. Creatine without the work does nothing.